# add class to widget_shopping_cart_content in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add class to widget_shopping_cart_content in WooCommerce without JS and Jquery. I want to filter fragment in function file.

JS and jquery are not working on this file.

I have found this code in class-wc-ajax.php file and I want to modify this code.

```
public static function get_refreshed_fragments() {
        ob_start();

        woocommerce_mini_cart();

        $mini_cart = ob_get_clean();

        $data = array(
            'fragments' => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', array(
                    'div.widget_shopping_cart_content' => '<div class="widget_shopping_cart_content">' . $mini_cart . '</div>',
                )
            ),
            'cart_hash' => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_hash', WC()->cart->get_cart_for_session() ? md5( json_encode( WC()->cart->get_cart_for_session() ) ) : '', WC()->cart->get_cart_for_session() ),
        );

        wp_send_json( $data );
    }
```

I want to add **dropdown-menu** class in this `<div class="widget_shopping_cart_content dropdown-menu">' . $mini_cart . '</div>';` but how can I didn't know.

Can please any one help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Option 1: str_replace();

```
add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'mm_string_replace_add_to_cart_fragments');

function mm_string_replace_add_to_cart_fragments($fragments){

    return $fragments['div.widget_shopping_cart_content'] = str_replace('class="widget_shopping_cart_content"', 'class="widget_shopping_cart_content dropdown-menu"', $fragments['div.widget_shopping_cart_content']);

}
```

This does not require additional call to `woocommerce_mini_cart()` and is much faster but less flexible then other method mentioned below.

## Option 2: Overwrite the `get_refreshed_fragments` function

```
add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'mm_change_add_to_cart_fragments');

function mm_change_add_to_cart_fragments(){
    ob_start();

    woocommerce_mini_cart();

    $mini_cart = ob_get_clean();

    return array(
        'div.widget_shopping_cart_content' => '<div class="widget_shopping_cart_content dropdown-menu">' . $mini_cart . '</div>',
                )

}
```

Essentially we are recalling the entire function but with some modifications. So first run on `get_refreshed_fragments` goes to waste. This is not ideal solution but this is what we have at hand. Use this if you want to modify the html in more detail.